# "Where's I pick up..."

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

From Deadpool Killustrated:
[image]

He says "Where's I pick up this little guy?", what does *where's* short for?

Comment: My first thought is a typo, and that it should read: "Where'd I pick up this little guy."

Comment: Sound like a slang usage. Say "Where(za) pick up this little guy?" fast and you might get the idea. The basic meaning might be "Where *to (do I)* pick up this little guy?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not really grammatical in this case, but usually is the contraction of "where is" in spoken AmE. I suspect that what he wanted to say is: "Where did.." or possibly "where is it ...". Some more context would help, such as the previous panes.